# Is a for loop necessary to dynamically create an array of particular numbers?

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to automatically create an array of the past 12 week numbers.

My immediate solution would be to do this:

```
for($week_number = date('W'); $week_number>date('W') - 12; $week_number--){
    $week_numbers[] = $week_number;
}
```

This will return an array of the past 12 week numbers (not tested).

However, my question is, is there a better way of achieving this? Is the for loop necessary?

Comment: What do you mean by "better"? If something as simple as using a `for` loop is somehow the bottleneck of your PHP application (which I **very, very seriously doubt**), then you've got bigger problems than trying to optimize away a `for` loop.

Comment: @JackManey There is absolutely nothing wrong with using for loops... What I effectively meant was, is there a PHP function that will achieve the same as I have illustrated. As Jon has kindly pointed out, yes there is :-). The range function does exactly what I need without the necessity of a for loop

Comment: @JackManey In fact, I am intrigued to know how you would have worded my question. I am looking for a 'better' solution than the one I already have... How on earth else could I have worded my question?? The bottom line is, there is a better solution than using a `for` loop, this being the `range` function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the [`range`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) function is a much cleaner way of doing the same:

```
$week_numbers = range(date('W'), date('W') - 11, -1);
```

Comment: This is the exact reason I asked the question. I knew there would be a clever PHP function to do this without a for loop. Thank you!

Comment: `-1` is not needed (at least in PHP 5.5) since PHP will recognize that end is below start (and result with -1 step by default).

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo: Nice touch, I didn't know it does that.